# Dúvida sobre seleção de itens no ListView

Tags: android

Como eu faço para quando eu "clicar" no ícone de "Voltar" do Android eu desseleciono todos os itens do ListView ao invés de encerrar a Activity?

Comment: Sobreescrever o evento de back deve resolver, não?

Comment: Se eu quiser sobreescrever esse método em um frament, é do mesmo jeito?

Comment: Imagino que sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicar no ícone voltar, imagino que seja o voltar padrão do OS Android, correto?

Para fazer isso, você deve fazer o **override** da função **onBackPressed** dentro da **activity** que você deseja que o comportamento padrão seja alterado (ou acrescentado de mais coisas).

Então dentro da função **onBackPressed** você tira a seleção de todos seus itens através do seu **adapter** utilizado para popular a ListView.

**OBS Importante**

Não é saudável, nem incentivado e muito menos recomendado que os eventos padrões de um OS seja sobrescritos de forma que altere seu comportamento padrão.

Pessoas que utilizam android estão acostumadas a clicar no voltar para realizar determinada ação, mudar isso pode causar um desconforto nos usuários da sua APP (jogos são exceção).

Apenas uma dica de padrões de desenvolvimento mobile.

Espero ter ajudado.